# Filter child relation set Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I have a Person entity with to-many relation to Salary and Expense entities.
I would like to filter the child Salary and Expense by date.

Either by NSPredicate or using Key path

Ex: Get Person.salary.@sum.salaryTotal where salaryDate > NSDate()

I have found something about SUBQUERY, but dont understand it quite. New to Swift.:)

Answer (score 0):

Posting an update with what I ended up doing:

```
var myFromDate: NSDate?
var myToDate: NSDate?

let expensesItem: NSObject = (personItem.relToExpenses?.filteredSetUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format:"(expenseDate >= %@ AND expenseDate =< %@)", myFromDate!, myToDate!)))!


    let expensesTotal = expensesItem.valueForKeyPath("@sum.expenseTotal") as? NSDecimalNumber ?? 0
```

And the same with Salary object

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, you need to look at what you have in memory and what not. The code you show does all its work in memory -- if the objects are already in memory then that'll give you the best performance. If not, it'll be faster to use a fetch request and set the predicate on it.

We write extensively about this trade-off in the **Performance** chapter of our Core Data book: https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/